# How to reverse the integration order of the double integral $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1+\cos\theta}r^2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)drd\theta$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am given the integral $$ \iint\limits_H \, (x+y) \mathrm{d} A $$
where $H$ is the area of the cardioid $r=cos(\theta)+1$.
I have translated the double integral to polar coordinates in order to solve it, where $\mathrm{d} A$ equals $r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin\theta$:
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1+\cos\theta}r^2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$ which equals:
$$ \frac{1}{3} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} (\sin\theta + \cos\theta + 3 \sin\theta \cos\theta + 3\cos^2 \theta + 3\sin\theta \cos^2\theta \\+3 \cos^3\theta + \sin\theta \cos^3\theta + \cos^4\theta )\mathrm{d} \theta. $$
After some calculations, this integral is equal to the solution which is $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. 
My question is now how to solve the double integral $$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{1+\cos\theta}r^2(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$ in the form of $$\int_{r=?}^{?}\int_{
\theta=?}^{?}(r^2\sin\theta+r^2\cos\theta )\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r.$$ So in essence, how to reverse the order of integration of this double integral. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: if $h$ and $f$ are continuous $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{f(\theta)} h(r,\theta) dr d\theta = \int_0^{A} \int_{U(r)} h(r,\theta) d\theta dr$ where $A = \max_\theta f(\theta)$ and $U(r) = \{ \theta \ | \ f(\theta) \ge r, \ \theta \in [0;2\pi] \}$ ???

Comment: I tried what you said, and came up with $\int_{r=0}^{2}\int_{
\theta=arccos(1-r)}^{2\pi}(r^2\sin\theta+r^2\cos\theta )\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r.$ However, that does not give me the same answer as the other integral. Do you know what I might have done wrong @user1952009 ?

Comment: I believe you want to take the inner limits of integration to be $-\cos^{-1}(r-1)$ and $\cos^{-1}(r-1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $0\le \theta \le \pi$, the relationship $r=1+\cos(\theta)$ implies the inverse relationship $\theta=\arccos(r-1)$.

And for $\pi\le\theta\le2\pi$, $r=1+\cos(\theta)$ implies the relationship $\theta = 2\pi -\arccos(r-1)$.

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1+\cos (\theta)}r^2(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))\,dr\,d\theta&=\int_0^2\int_0^{\arccos(r-1)} r^2(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))\,d\theta\,dr\\\\
&+\int_0^2\int_{2\pi-\arccos(r-1)}^{2\pi}r^2(\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))\,d\theta\,dr\\\\
&=2\int_0^2\int_0^{\arccos(r-1)} r^2\cos(\theta)\,d\theta\,dr\\\\
&=2\int_0^2r^2\sqrt{r(2-r)}\,dr\\\\
&=\frac{5\pi}{4}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result obtained in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do is to make the limits generic. Note that $1+cos\theta \in [0,2]$. Write $1(\cdot)$ for the indicator function. So, informally, write
$$ \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{1+\cos\theta}
= \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^2 1(r \le 1+\cos\theta).$$
You can now swap the integrals without any concern about the limits*. Now, we know that $r \le 1+\cos\theta \iff \cos\theta \ge r-1$ so this becomes
$$ \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{1+\cos\theta}
= \int_{r=0}^2 \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} 1(\cos\theta \ge r-1)
= \int_{r=0}^2 \int_{\theta \in \Theta}$$
where $\Theta$ is the range of $\theta$ for which $\cos\theta \ge r-1$, where $r \in [0,2]$, which I'll leave for you to calculate. This will then give you the result.

*Note that sometimes you can't actually swap the order of integration, but this is a different question to what you're saying.

Comment: After some calculations I thought that the range of $\theta$ such that $\cos\theta \geq r-1$ equalled $\cos^{-1}(r-1)$ to $2\pi$, but inputting that range into the double integral gives a very different answer than $\frac{5\pi}{4}$. Could you tell me if that range is correct and if not, tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: If you recall, $\theta \mapsto \cos\theta$ *is not* an increasing function, so you can't just do what you (or at least I!) would naively hope. You have to look for the roots. You know that $r-1 \le 1$ as $r \le 2$, so $\cos 0 = \cos(2\pi) \ge r-1$. You then need to find the other ends. These will be given by the two solutions to $\cos\theta = r-1$. Consider these solutions in $[0,2\pi]$, call them $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, with $\theta_1 < \theta_2$. The range is then $[0,\theta_1] \cup [\theta_2, 2\pi]$. so $\int_\Theta = \int_0^{\theta_1} + \int_{\theta_2}^{2\pi}$. Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: Note, by the symmetry (evenness) of $\cos$, that $\theta_2 = 2\pi - \theta_1$.

Comment: Dr. MV then gives the explicit calculation. I didn't give this because I tend to favour the OP working out the details for themselves, as I think that's advantageous to them. I recommend that you do so without looking again at Dr. MV's answer; you can then use his answer to check. :)